# Boot custom precise live cd via ipxe

Tags: live-cd, pxe

I configured isc-dhcp, ipxe and tftpboot so I can boot over network via PXE. It works the ubuntu netinstall image is booting nice with pxelinux.0.

I created a custom live cd with this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch. It boots nicely in an VM.

Now I wan't to connect this image to my pxe environment. The best would be to boot and append the disk via http.
There are plenty of tutorials. But I can't get the squashfs mounted. What is the best way to do this. Do I need pxelinux, do I need NFS? I'm confused about all the different bootloaders.

Help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

part of dhcpd.conf

```
next-server 10.1.1.1;
if exists user-class and option user-class = "iPXE" {
   filename "menu.ipxe";
} else {
   filename "undionly.kpxe";
}
```

and menu.ipxe

```
#!ipxe

set smartos-build 20121004T212912Z

######## MAIN MENU ###################
:start
menu Welcome
item
item --gap -- ------------------------- Operating systems ------------------------------
item cellos-storage     Boot CellOS
item smartos    Boot SmartOS (${smartos-build})
item ubuntu     Boot Ubuntu Precise 12.04 netinstall
item --gap -- ------------------------------ Utilities ---------------------------------
item shell      Enter iPXE shell
item reboot     Reboot
item
item exit       Exit (boot local disk)
choose --default cellos-storage --timeout 5000 target && goto ${target}




########## UTILITY ITEMS ####################
:shell
echo Type exit to get the back to the menu
shell
set menu-timeout 0
goto start

:reboot
reboot

:exit
exit

########## MENU ITEMS #######################


:cellos-storage
kernel /cellos/storage/cellos-latest/casper/vmlinuz
initrd /cellos/storage/cellos-latest/casper/initrd.lz
#chain http://10.1.1.1/boot/cellos/storage/cellos-latest.iso
boot

# SmartOS Root shadow is "root"
:smartos
kernel /smartos/${smartos-build}/platform/i86pc/kernel/amd64/unix -B root_shadow='$5$2HOHRnK3$NvLlm.1KQBbB0WjoP7xcIwGnllhzp2HnT.mDO7DpxYA'
initrd /smartos/${smartos-build}/platform/i86pc/amd64/boot_archive
boot
:ubuntu
kernel /ubuntu/precise/netinstall/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
initrd /ubuntu/precise/netinstall/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
boot
goto start
```

Answer (score 3):

Did this with Linux Mint 13, but should be the same with Ubuntu 12.04.  I used mintconstructor to customize my live-dvd but should work LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch.

I was able to configure net booting from a live-dvd using only iPXE (no pxelinux).

To do so, I configured a http server (with apache) to publish content in /var/www.  It's necessary because the initrd and vmlinuz need to be accessible through http.

I took the initrd.lz and vmlinuz from the live-dvd and put it into /var/www

Took all the files in /casper (from live-dvd) and put it in /var/www/casper.

On your web server, publish also an NFS share of /var/www so the files are also accessible through NFS.  That is necessary for accessing the squashfs (casper folder) through the network (doesn't seem to work through http).

Here's my /etc/exports (NFS)

```
/var/www *(ro,async)
```

Your iPXE script should look like this (replace the IP accordingly) :

```
#!ipxe
initrd http://10.54.9.43/initrd.lz
chain http://10.54.9.43/vmlinuz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.54.9.43:/var/www/ initrd=initrd.lz
```

That will load the kernel and initrd through http, and the squashfs through NFS...

About the DHCP part, I'm using a Windows Server DHCP ... so I could not help you. Follow the documentation of iPXE.  For others, here's what I did : I configured a TFTP server on the same server (linux).  I configured option 66 to the IP of that server (on the DHCP server).  I put undionly.kpxe (iPXE) in the TFTP folder of my server to chainload iPXE (check iPXE doc). I configured option 67 as specified in the iPXE doc to prevent an infinite loop (because of the chainload).

All this was a bit diffult for me to find out because there's not much documentation about this on the web.